# How to solve differential equations with silence period (using DifferentialEquations.jl)?

Tags: julia

I want to solve a differential equation that has some "silence period" (I'm not sure whether it has a formal name or not, it means during this period that the system is static and not controlled by the differential equation).

For example (see the figure), when a free-fall ball touches the ground, the callback function will be triggered. It enters this "silence period" (dash line in the figure), after this period, it keeps following the differential equation (the parameters can be change or not, as in the figure I reset the height of the ball).

[image: Example trace]

I know it can be done by for loop, but currently I try to use DifferentialEquations.jl, so I wonder if I can set a callback or use other methods to accomplish it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can flip a parameter to zero with a `DiscreteCallback` to zero all of the derivative terms, and turn it off after the silence period.

Comment: This idea is nice, thank you!
But How can I switch the parameter back after the period? It is like that setting another callback function dynamically?   
Another question, why not use `ContinuousCallback` as the example in [Example 1: Bouncing Ball](https://docs.juliadiffeq.org/latest/features/callback_functions.html)?

Comment: Just have your callback check for two values, and do something differently depending on `t`. `ContinuousCallback` are slightly more expensive and mostly for the case where the times are defined implicitly instead of already known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to set a parameter to zero using a `DiscreteCallback`, and having a second callback un-zero it. [The callback handling page](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/features/callback_functions.html) describes in more detail how to define and use such callbacks.